# Xcode Openssl RSA decryption function needed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, encryption, openssl, rsa

I am reading an encrypted string from an application in xcode and I have to write a function that uses RSA decryption to decode and display the message.

I am completely lost on where to begin with this.

I have Openssl complied in xcode and I am using the openssl/rsa.h file.

I am trying to use the function:

```
RSA_private_decrypt(int flen, const unsigned char *from, unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);
```

But then I'd read somewhere on the Openssl main site that the function just returns a number and not the actual string. I also have no idea what paramenters to pass through.

The only reference I have found is the openssl/rsa.h file and looking at the functions it contains.

I've tried doing some research the past couple hours but I have no found any answers.

I was wondering if there is a simple function that I can pass my encrypted string and my private key (using a file or hardcoded) and it can return the decrypted string?

If not is there a guide on how to use Openssl with Objective C programming?

Please let me know if you need more information on the issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look Apple's example which uses security transforms (this avoids openssl) in their [Security Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/Security_Overview/Introduction/Introduction.html).

With a bit of luck you can do things with apple transforms and go with that programme.

If not - or if for some reason you really want to use openssl; then the openssl source contains the example file `openssl-0.9.8t/apps/rsa.c` which pretty much allows for selective cut-and-paste to make things work.

Doing `man RSA_private_decrypt` from the command line will show you the manual page (or from within Xcode  to the man page). Or see http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_public_encrypt.html.

Example use for the above:

```
unsigned char in[] = { 1, 2, ... byte array to decrypt };
// size of that in byte array
int inlen = sizeof(in);

// output buffer size depends on the key type.
char * out = malloc(RSA_size(rsa)); 

int e = RSA_private_decrypt(inlen, in, out, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
```

where padding is one of the values from the man-page.

The value of rsa is a bit more complex to initialise as this is where you set up your keys and what not. Check the above rsa.c file for examples of various ways of filling it - it normally boils down to something like:

```
EVP_PKEY *pkey = load_key( ... , password,... );
rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pkey);
```

where `load_key` is borrowed from the app examples of openssl.

Comment: Sorry I am still having trouble understanding this. What is the byte array to decrypt that is needed in the in array. Does it matter what I initialize out and rsa too? What does the load key function need besides password and why are you calling giving rsa the value of the private key?

Comment: ok - the byte array 'in' corresponds to your "encrypted string from an application in xcode". Once you decrypt it - you get a new byte array - now in 'out'. In order to decrypt something one needs a key. An RSA key in this case as you say 'RSA decryption'.

Comment: I was trying some of your commands and I got this error:Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_RSA_size", referenced from:
      -[ViewController barcodeData:type:] in ViewController.o
  "_RSA_private_decrypt", referenced from:
      -[ViewController barcodeData:type:] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386   Any idea how to fix this? I put some extra details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525706/openssl-mach-o-linker-error-for-architecture-i386-and-armv7

Comment: You are linking against openssl (libcrypto.dylib) ?

Comment: I can't locate that file. I only have libcrypto.a, would this file still work the same?

Comment: Don't forget to free the ```RSA*``` by calling ```RSA_free``` !